# moment.js and to get the trailing date in a calendar view

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Given today is October 2015, in a calendar view, the September 27 - 29 appear on the calendar and Oct 31 appear. I'd like to get the start date that is appearing on the calendar AND the end date, so in this case, it'd be 9/27/2015 and 10/31/2015.

I'm using moment.js to try and calculate this. My thought is I'd get the calendar week and then convert that to find the start date and then get the end week the calendar is showing and convert that to get the last date shown. Its proving to be quite challenging which makes me thinking there is an easier way.

I'm looking at the documentation found here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/ but I'm having trouble chaining some of the events together.

I have this to get me the month of the year:

```
var day = '2015-10-19';
var getStartWeekYear = moment(day).startOf("month").week();
var getEndDateWeekYear = moment(day).endOf("month").week();
```

and this is returning the expected value of 40 and 44 for the given date (day) but what would the next step be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easier than you think. :)

```
var day = '2015-10-19';
var start = moment(day).startOf('month').startOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var end = moment(day).endOf('month').endOf('week').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(start); // "2015-09-27"
console.log(end);   // "2015-10-31"
```

Comment: Thank you! That was easier than I thought. I was close on one of my attempts, I had `var start = moment(day).startOf("month").week();`

Comment: Yes, you were close. :)  The `week` function is for getting or setting weeks by week number, but in this case the week number itself isn't important, just that you *move* to the start or the end of the week.   Also keep in mind that the day-of-week that a week starts on is locale specific.  That's probably what you want, but you could instead use `isoWeek`, which will *always* start the week on a Monday.

Comment: locale specific is what we want but this is a good point for anyone else to consider who stumbles upon this. +1